kivy "configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables Resolving the "See `config.log' for more details" error
https://github.com/hyun071111/kivyapp
I'm making an Android app with kivy, but I keep getting an error... Can anyone help me?
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in \_run_module_as_main
return \_run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in \_run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "/mnt/d/hackerton/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1256, in \<module\>
main()
File "/mnt/d/hackerton/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
ToolchainCL()
File "/mnt/d/hackerton/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 685, in __init__
getattr(self, command)(args)
File "/mnt/d/hackerton/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 104, in wrapper_func
build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
File "/mnt/d/hackerton/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 163, in build_dist_from_args
build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx,
File "/mnt/d/hackerton/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 504, in build_recipes
recipe.build_arch(arch)
File "/mnt/d/hackerton/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipes/libffi/__init__.py", line 30, in build_arch  
shprint(sh.Command('./configure'),
File "/mnt/d/hackerton/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 167, in shprint
for line in output:
File "/home/qkrgusdnr/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 915, in next
self.wait()
File "/home/qkrgusdnr/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 845, in wait
self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
File "/home/qkrgusdnr/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 869, in handle_command_exit_code
raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_77:

RAN: /mnt/d/hackerton/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/libffi/configure --host=aarch64-linux-android --prefix=/mnt/d/hackerton/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/libffi --disable-builddir --enable-shared

STDOUT:
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... aarch64-unknown-linux-android
checking target system type... aarch64-unknown-linux-android
checking for gsed... sed
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for aarch64-linux-android-strip... /home/qkrgusdnr/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/llvm-strip --strip-unneeded
checking for a race-free mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make -j12 sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make -j12 supports nested variables... yes
checking for aarch64-linux-android-gcc... /usr/bin/ccache /home/qkrgusdnr/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -target aarch64-linux-android21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv8-a -fPIC
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/mnt/d/hackerton/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/libffi': configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables See `config.log' for more details

STDERR:

# Command failed: \['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pythonforandroid.toolchain', 'create', '--dist_name=eyein', '--bootstrap=sdl2', '--requirements=python3,kivy,opencv-python-headless,numpy,tensorflow,tensorflow_hub,pyttsx3', '--arch=arm64-v8a', '--arch=armeabi-v7a', '--copy-libs', '--color=always', '--storage-dir=/mnt/d/hackerton/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a', '--ndk-api=21', '--ignore-setup-py', '--debug'\]

# ENVIRONMENT:

# SHELL = '/bin/bash'

# WSL2_GUI_APPS_ENABLED = '1'

# WSL_DISTRO_NAME = 'Ubuntu'

# NAME = 'DESKTOP-KNK30L5'

# PWD = '/mnt/d/hackerton/app'

# LOGNAME = 'qkrgusdnr'

# HOME = '/home/qkrgusdnr'

# LANG = 'C.UTF-8'

# WSL_INTEROP = '/run/WSL/65382_interop'

# LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.webp=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'

# WAYLAND_DISPLAY = 'wayland-0'

# LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'

# TERM = 'xterm-256color'

# LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'

# USER = 'qkrgusdnr'

# DISPLAY = ':0'

# SHLVL = '1'

# XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000/'

# WSLENV = ''

# XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'

# PATH = ('/home/qkrgusdnr/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/qkrgusdnr/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/wsl/lib:/mnt/d/Program '

'Files (x86)/VMware/VMware '
'Workstation/bin/:/mnt/c/Windows/system32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Program '
'Files/nodejs/:/mnt/c/MinGW/bin:/mnt/c/Users/admin/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start '
'Menu/Programs/Python '
'3.9:/mnt/c/Users/admin/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start '
'Menu/Programs/Python '
'3.9/Script:/mnt/c/Users/admin/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start '
'Menu/Programs/Python '
'3.12:/mnt/c/Users/admin/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start '
'Menu/Programs/Python 3.12/Script:/mnt/c/Program '
'Files/Git/cmd:/Docker/host/bin:/mnt/c/Users/admin/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/Scripts/:/mnt/c/Users/admin/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/:/mnt/c/Users/admin/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start '
'Menu/Programs/Python '
'3.12:/mnt/c/Users/admin/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/admin/AppData/Roaming/npm:/mnt/d/Users/admin/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft '
'VS Code/bin:/mnt/d/Program Files/JetBrains/PyCharm '
'2024.1/bin:/mnt/c/Users/admin/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WinGet/Packages/Schniz.fnm_Microsoft.Winget.Source_8wekyb3d8bbwe:/snap/bin')

# DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus'

# HOSTTYPE = 'x86_64'

# PULSE_SERVER = 'unix:/mnt/wslg/PulseServer'

# \_ = '/home/qkrgusdnr/.local/bin/buildozer'

# OLDPWD = '/mnt/d/hackerton'

# PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/qkrgusdnr/.buildozer/android/packages'

# ANDROIDSDK = '/home/qkrgusdnr/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'

# ANDROIDNDK = '/home/qkrgusdnr/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b'

# ANDROIDAPI = '31'

# ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'

# 

# Buildozer failed to execute the last command

# The error might be hidden in the log above this error

# Please read the full log, and search for it before

# raising an issue with buildozer itself.

# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2

